# Как не потерять локальные изменения, если надо сделать git pull?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, git-pull

При попытке запушить код в репозиторий, git ругнулся и сказал, что есть свежие изменения, а значит надо сделать pull. При подтягиваний изменений с сервера не слетит ли мой локальный коммит и смогу ли я его потом запушить в удаленный репозиторий ?

Answer (score 5):

Перед pull можно сделать коммит, или прописать команду git stash, чтобы все изменения сохранились временно в нём, при этом Ваш проект "откатывается" до версии сервера. При неправильном pull можно вызвать ненужный merge, если сделать коммит, при pull все коммиты с сервера просто соединяются с Вашим.

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался , ничего плохого не произойдет. В самом худшем случае, если свежие изменение затронули ваши файлы, то придется все смержить и запушить уже свои изменения.